# Sleuthkit -- Error while loading shared libraries

Tags: c, ubuntu, shared-libraries, xen

After successfully building and compiling ***sleuthkit library*** [4.2 version], I tried to write an introspection tool using the library.. Thing is whenever i am trying to compile the program in order to test it and I am using a function from the library API I'm get the following error :

```
error while loading shared libraries: libtsk.so.13: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I found thought that this file exists in ***/usr/local/lib*** folder . Am i missing something ? *./configure && make* didn't give me any errors.. and I am including *-ltsk* on the makefile!

My pc information : **XEN** hypervisor [*Ubuntu* 12.04 x64bit] and i am trying to investigate a guest vm running ubuntu *12.04* x32bit

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try 'export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib' before running your program.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,  still doesn't fix the issue. I am still getting  the same error  : /

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to the problem , if I install -dev package...

```
sudo apt-get install libtsk-dev
```

Also read this useful  [article](https://lonesysadmin.net/2013/02/22/error-while-loading-shared-libraries-cannot-open-shared-object-file/)... Understood why exactly that happened .

Comment: Does not work..